# presentOpenInMenu shows all options on trying to share image in instagram

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, instagram, ios11

I am trying to share an image from my application to Instagram. I have followed all the steps mentioned here. 
https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

Here is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

lazy private var documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()

func shareImageOnInstagram()
{
    let image = UIImage(named: "sample")
    let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL! as URL) {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let saveImagePath = (documentsPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent("Image.igo")
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
        do {
          try imageData?.write(to: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: saveImagePath), options: NSData.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        } catch {
            print("Instagram sharing error")
        }
        documentInteractionController.url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: saveImagePath)
        documentInteractionController.uti = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
        if !self.documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true) {
            print("Instagram not found")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Instagram not found")
    }
}

@IBAction func onShowInstagramClicked(_ sender: Any)
{
    self.shareImageOnInstagram()
} 
}
```

**In iOS 11.1 whenever onShowInstagramClicked is called, it shows all other applications including instagram.**

[image]

**Same piece of code works perfectly fine on iOS 10.3.2** and shows instagram (and Notes)

[image]

**Is there any extra thing necessary for iOS 11 ?**